# How to add another function after changing the app mode in RxSwift

Tags: function, rx-swift, uiswitch

I have a switcher that changes the app theme.

```
        switchButton.rx
            .controlEvent(.valueChanged)
            .withLatestFrom(themeService.typeStream)
            .map { $0 == .dark ? .light : .dark }
            .bind(to: themeService.switcher)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I want to add another custom function when an app theme changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed to subscribe to an Observable more than once.

```
let theme = switchButton.rx
    .controlEvent(.valueChanged)
    .withLatestFrom(themeService.typeStream)
    .map { $0 == .dark ? .light : .dark }
    .share()

theme
    .bind(to: themeService.switcher)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

theme
    .bind(to: anotherCustomFunction)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: `
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'light'
`
ERROR showing like this

Comment: Need more information.

Comment: It's finished. thanks a lot.